# Inject external javascript file out of time

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, inject

I want to load an external javascript. This javascript contains source for an ad. I use a method of injection because the javascript needs the user IP. The javascript code to use is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">var userip;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://service.get.userip?var=userip"></script>
        <script>

            var url="http://example.com/abc?user_ip=" + userip;

            var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.src = url;
            headID.appendChild(newScript);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I use a  service javascript to get the IP of user ("http://service.get.userip?var=userip" in this example code). Then I added the user IP to the url where I download the javascript.

The javascript is inserted when it revised the web charged with developer mode browser but it doesn't work.

I think the problem is that the JavaScrip injection is slow and this is no time to charge properly.

In my tests I got a proper operation to put a alert before the end of the last script:

```
<script>
    ...
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
    alert("Script is Load!");
</script>
```

For this reason I think the problem is load time. I also try loops, sleep() and setTimeout(), but I do not reproduce the smooth running that I get with the alert().

Comment: That completely depends on how that script works

Comment: is `userip` defined before you set `url`? add a `newScript.onload = function(){};` to see how long it is taking to load in.